# PHOP headers - Opening a CSV file from PHP script

Tags: php, csv, header

I have the below code to open a CSV  file, but for some reason it looks to be converting `shopkeeper/89137.csv` to `shopkeeper_89137.csv`.  It keeps opening a blank csv file obviously because its looking for a file that isnt there. What is the proper way to reference a file in order to open it?

```
            header("Content-type: text/csv");
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=shopkeeper/89137.csv");
            header("Pragma: no-cache");
            header("Expires: 0");
```

Comment: hmm, you talk about "open a CSV file", but you actually stream it to the client's browser...

Comment: As far as I know, those are the headers that are sent to the browser indicating that content of a file is being sent rather than the content itself. Are you outputting the content in some way? The filename is simply the name of the file the browser will use when presenting the download.

Comment: @BrendanBullen "indicating that content of a file is being sent rather than the content itself" - had to read this a couple of times ;-)

Comment: @Leon After coming back to it after 16 hours, so did I! I think "indicating that content of a file is being sent rather than producing the content itself" would have been better. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The headers should only include the base name of the file being sent.  On the receiving end of things, it thinks you're trying to pass it a file with the name "shopkeeper/89137.csv" which, on most operating systems, contains an illegal character (/) for a file name, so it gets converted to an underscore.

You should probably tweak the line to read:

`header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=89137.csv");`

Answer (score 2):

Referencing file paths is not ideal in the HTTP header. You must reference only "89137.csv" for the filename, and then process your file by appending "shopkeeper/" to the filename in your file opening function. Remember that you can still use variables in the header string parameter.

Comment: according to [the spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2183.txt) you cannot reference file paths at all. Besides, these headers will open a SaveAs dialog at the user's browser, so how should the OP using script "append shopkeeper/ to the filename in your file opening function"?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the `/` character is reserved and cannot be used as a filename!!

I would reconsider your naming scheme...